# How to unban from fail2ban?

Tags: ssh, fail2ban

fail2ban banned my ip for SSH.
In email I received that said I got banned via fail2ban after 5 attempts against SSH.
Which is not even truth i wasn't even loging to SSH.
I can still access webmin.
I shut down fail2ban and still same.
For `iptables -L` it shows this.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fail2ban-SSH  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain fail2ban-SSH (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I tried with

```
fail2ban-client set ssh-iptables unbanip myIP
then it returned this:
IP myIP is not banned
```

I tried with this too:

```
iptables -D fail2ban-ssh-iptables -s myIP -j DROP
```

And didn't recieve anything and I am still banned.

```
> fail2ban-client status
Status
|- Number of jail:  1
`- Jail list:       ssh-iptables
```

I am also getting a lot of this emails:

```
Banned the following ip addresses on Thu Nov 14 20:05:01 EST 2013

282 with 282 connections
```

xxx      xxx  numbers different

Comment: Your firewall shows that **nobody** is banned. Why do you think you are?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use this command on the chain `fail2ban-ssh-iptables`:

```
iptables -D fail2ban-ssh-iptables -s myIP -j DROP
```

But your `iptables –L –n` shows repeated references to the chain `fail2ban-SSH` which is the chain that is string the `fail2ban` rules. So that command should be:

```
iptables -D fail2ban-SSH -s myIP -j DROP
```

Comment: i did `iptables -D fail2ban-SSH -s myIP -j DROP`
and get this (didn't shown this in webmin)
iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).

Comment: Did you replace the `myIP` in that command with your IP address?

Comment: Yep i replaced it

Comment: Anyone pls help
Now i am totaly locked out. Webpage don't work same webmin
Serial Console on solusVM don't work
Shut down then boot don't work